# code cannot function: Javascript&HTML Auto display price according to selected value of multiple dropdown using if else

Tags: javascript, html

User is gonna choose the attribute they want in the business card product and the code will automatically display the price according to the attribute the user has chosen from the drop-down menu. I think the error might be in the javascript part but I don't know what is the error.

Below, is the code:

```
    <div class="a">PRODUCT: BUSINESS CARD</div>
    <!--table--> 
    <form id="businesscard" method="post" action="">

        <table border="1"width="50%">
            <col style="width:15%">
            <col style="width:35%">
            <!--form title-->

            <tr>
                <td>Size</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="size" id="size" placeholder="54mm x 89mm" size="75"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paper</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="paper" id="paper" placeholder="Gloss Art Card 250gsm" size="75"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td><select name="quantity" id="quantity" onchange="calculateAmount()">
                    <option value="0" disabled selected>--Choose quantity--</option>
                    <option value="1">100</option>
                    <option value="2">300</option>
                    <option value="3">500</option>
                    <option value="4">1000</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Orientation </td>
                <td>
                   <select name="orientation" id="orientation">
                    <option value="0" disabled selected>--Choose Orientation--</option>
                    <option value="landscape">Landscape</option>
                    <option value="potrait">Potrait</option>
                  </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finishing </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="finishing" id="finishing" onchange="calculateAmount()">
                    <option value="0" disabled selected>--Choose Finishing--</option>
                    <option value="matte">Matte Lamination</option>
                    <option value="gloss">Gloss Lamination</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Corner Shape</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="corner" id="corner" onchange="calculateAmount()">
                    <option value disabled selected="0">--Choose Corner--</option>
                    <option value="square">Square Corner</option>
                    <option value="round">Round Corner</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><!--payment-->
                <th colspan="2">Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Order Total:RM</td>
                <td><input name="tot_amount" id="tot_amount" type="text" readonly></td>
            </tr><!--end payment-->
 
        </table>
    </form>


    <script>

            function calculateAmount() {  
                var q = document.getElementById("quantity");
                var f = document.getElementById("finishing");
                var c = document.getElementById("corner");
                var selFrst = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;
                var selScnd = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;
                var selThrd = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;

                var tot_price;

                if(selFrst==1)
                {
                    if(selScnd==matte)
                    {
                        
                        if(selThrd==square)
                        {
                            tot_price="25";
                        }
                        else if(selThrd==round)
                        {
                            tot_price="30";
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else if(selScnd==gloss)
                    {
                        if(selThrd==square)
                        {
                            tot_price="30";
                        }
                        else if(selThrd==round)
                        {
                            tot_price="35";
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if(selFrst==2)
                {
                    if(selScnd==matte)
                    {
                        
                        if(selThrd==square)
                        {
                            tot_price="35";
                        }
                        else if(selThrd==round)
                        {
                            tot_price="50";
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else if(selScnd==gloss)
                    {
                        if(selThrd==square)
                        {
                            tot_price="40";
                        }
                        else if(selThrd==round)
                        {
                            tot_price="55";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(selFrst==3)
                {
                    if(selScnd==matte)
                    {
                        
                        if(selThrd==square)
                        {
                           tot_price="45";
                        }
                        else if(selThrd==round)
                        {
                            tot_price="70";
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else if(selScnd==gloss)
                    {
                        if(selThrd==square)
                        {
                            tot_price="50";
                        }
                        else if(selThrd==round)
                        {
                            tot_price="75";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(selFrst==4)
                {
                    if(selScnd==matte)
                    {
                        
                        if(selThrd==square)
                        {
                            tot_price="55";
                        }
                        else if(selThrd==round)
                        {
                            tot_price="105";
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else if(selScnd==gloss)
                    {
                        if(selThrd==square)
                        {
                            tot_price="60";
                        }
                        else if(selThrd==round)
                        {
                            tot_price="115";
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                /*display the result*/
                
                document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
            }
        </script> <!--end table-->
```

Comment: `if(selScnd==matte)` Where is `matte` defined? Did you mean `== "matte"`? If `matte` is undefined, this if-statement will fail. This also applies to every other if-statement for `selScnd` and `selThrd`.

Comment: I had followed your instruction and it works! thanks you are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround string values with quotes

```
<script>

    function calculateAmount() {  
        var q = document.getElementById("quantity");
        var f = document.getElementById("finishing");
        var c = document.getElementById("corner");
        var selFrst = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value;
        var selScnd = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;
        var selThrd = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;

        var tot_price;
                    
        console.log(selFrst);
        console.log(selScnd);
        console.log(selThrd);
        if(selFrst==1)
        {
            if(selScnd=='matte')
            {
                
                if(selThrd=='square')
                {
                    tot_price="25";
                }
                else if(selThrd=='round')
                {
                    tot_price="30";
                }
                
            }
            else if(selScnd=='gloss')
            {
                if(selThrd=='square')
                {
                    tot_price="30";
                }
                else if(selThrd=='round')
                {
                    tot_price="35";
                }
            }
        }

        else if(selFrst==2)
        {
            if(selScnd=='matte')
            {
                
                if(selThrd=='square')
                {
                    tot_price="35";
                }
                else if(selThrd=='round')
                {
                    tot_price="50";
                }
                
            }
            else if(selScnd=='gloss')
            {
                if(selThrd=='square')
                {
                    tot_price="40";
                }
                else if(selThrd=='round')
                {
                    tot_price="55";
                }
            }
        }
        else if(selFrst==3)
        {
            if(selScnd=='matte')
            {
                
                if(selThrd=='square')
                {
                   tot_price="45";
                }
                else if(selThrd=='round')
                {
                    tot_price="70";
                }
                
            }
            else if(selScnd=='gloss')
            {
                if(selThrd=='square')
                {
                    tot_price="50";
                }
                else if(selThrd=='round')
                {
                    tot_price="75";
                }
            }
        }
        else if(selFrst==4)
        {
            if(selScnd=='matte')
            {
                
                if(selThrd=='square')
                {
                    tot_price="55";
                }
                else if(selThrd=='round')
                {
                    tot_price="105";
                }
                
            }
            else if(selScnd=='gloss')
            {
                if(selThrd=='square')
                {
                    tot_price="60";
                }
                else if(selThrd=='round')
                {
                    tot_price="115";
                }
            }
        }
        
        /*display the result*/
        
        document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the line do? console.log(selFrst);
        console.log(selScnd);
        console.log(selThrd);

Comment: It just prints the value of the variables selFrst,selScnd,selThrd on to the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The mistake is in javascript.

The values selected from a dropdown are of type string in Javascript. String are delimited with "" or ''. In your code the selected values such as 1, matte and square are not within quotes. Hence the words like  matte and square are being interpreted as undefined variables and the selected values of 0,1,2, etc as numbers.

Here is the corrected JS code.

```
function calculateAmount() {  
        var q = document.getElementById("quantity");
        var f = document.getElementById("finishing");
        var c = document.getElementById("corner");
        var selFrst = q.value;
        var selScnd = f.value;
        var selThrd = c.value;

        var tot_price = 0;

        if(selFrst=="1")
        {
            if(selScnd=="matte")
            {
                
                if(selThrd=="square")
                {
                    tot_price="25";
                }
                else if(selThrd=="round")
                {
                    tot_price="30";
                }
                
            }
            else if(selScnd=="gloss")
            {
                if(selThrd=="square")
                {
                    tot_price="30";
                }
                else if(selThrd=="round")
                {
                    tot_price="35";
                }
            }
        }

        else if(selFrst=="2")
        {
            if(selScnd=="matte")
            {
                
                if(selThrd=="square")
                {
                    tot_price="35";
                }
                else if(selThrd=="round")
                {
                    tot_price="50";
                }
                
            }
            else if(selScnd=="gloss")
            {
                if(selThrd=="square")
                {
                    tot_price="40";
                }
                else if(selThrd=="round")
                {
                    tot_price="55";
                }
            }
        }
        else if(selFrst=="3")
        {
            if(selScnd=="matte")
            {
                
                if(selThrd=="square")
                {
                   tot_price="45";
                }
                else if(selThrd=="round")
                {
                    tot_price="70";
                }
                
            }
            else if(selScnd=="gloss")
            {
                if(selThrd=="square")
                {
                    tot_price="50";
                }
                else if(selThrd=="round")
                {
                    tot_price="75";
                }
            }
        }
        else if(selFrst=="4")
        {
            if(selScnd=="matte")
            {
                
                if(selThrd=="square")
                {
                    tot_price="55";
                }
                else if(selThrd=="round")
                {
                    tot_price="105";
                }
                
            }
            else if(selScnd=="gloss")
            {
                if(selThrd=="square")
                {
                    tot_price="60";
                }
                else if(selThrd=="round")
                {
                    tot_price="115";
                }
            }
        }
        
        /*display the result*/
        
        document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
    }
```

One more thing The value of option chosen with  can be retrieved easily using `document.getElementById("something").value` instead of `var q = document.getElementById("something"); var selFrst = q.options[q.selectedIndex].value`